# How to have Google Form retrieve data from a Google Sheet based on user input?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I work for a local school district and have been tasked with creating registration forms for our All-County band/orchestra ensemble auditions. My desired outcome is to be able to have a student enter his/her school ID number into a Google Form and for his name and other demographic information to pre-populate from another Google Sheet.  I know that I can achieve this outcome with add-ons like FormRanger, but we are a district of over 35,000 students which I'm afraid would break the add-on, or at the least take forever to load.

Is this possible even?  I am pretty much a novice when it comes to google scripts, but and savvy enough to be able to search and follow directions.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible by using Google Forms but you could create URL that will pre-fill the form.

One way, is that you create a pre-filled form URL for each student, then send the corresponding URL to each student but maybe you will have more control over the process if you create a web application instead of using Google Forms.

To create this web application you could use Google Apps Script but you should learn about HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: I think that he is asking if he can do a lookup like in Excel, where you take the unique ID and pull a row from another spreadsheet based on that. So value 4394 pulls row 500 where cell A500 = 4394, and then B500:Z500 is returned as well. I'm not certain that he needs to pre-fill the form?

Comment: IMHO that is not what the question says: "My desired outcome is to be able to have a student enter his/her school ID number **into a Google Form**..."

Comment: The rest of that line makes it sound like he is asking about being able to retrieve the data based on input, but if his goal is to use that to fill out the rest of the form then Google Apps Script would be the move forward. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I just expressed my opinion, the OP is the one that should clarify what they meant.

Comment: Thanks, Sean Brookins. I think you correctly understood what I’m wanting to do. Any ideas on a script I might be able to use? Sorry for any confusion. I’m very much a novice when it goes to Google Apps Script

Comment: @AustinWyatt Please edit your question to clarify what are you looking for. (by the way add a @ to usernames to notify them about your comment)

Comment: @Rubén Thanks for your help. Clearly, I’m new to posting here. Thanks for your patience.